# How to create a map like the attached one?

Tags: cartography, maps

I have come across some maps (visualizations) similar to the one attached and I would like to learn how to make them.

I work with ArcGIS Pro and QGIS extensively, however, I think this is more a product of graphic design. I guess it was used Adobe Photoshop or Illustrator to make it. But this is only an assumption.

Do you know what software is used to create these type of maps and if there are available online courses?

[image]

Comment: Daniel Huffman tutorials and walkthroughs will give you some pointer (https://somethingaboutmaps.wordpress.com/tutorials/)